# How to count text fields that are not empty with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to count text fields that are not empty with JQuery?

Here's how I thought:

```
var cnt = 0;

$.each($("input[name=items]"), function(i){
   if($(this).val() != ""){
       cnt++;
   } 
});
```

If I use this codes, I have to write each function unconditionally. This is a waste of somehow, but is there any other way? Or is this the best way?

Comment: Why do you think the existing code is bad?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal No. I just wanted to know if there is another way besides the above code

Comment: @undefined Sorry. I got a typo in the code and fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no selector to retrieve empty `input` elements, so the only way to achieve what you require is through a loop. You can use an implicit loop, though, by using `filter()` instead of `each()`, like this:

```
var cnt = $('input[name="items"]').filter(function() {
  return this.value.trim() == '';
}).length;
```

If you don't need IE support, then this code can be shortened using an ES6 arrow function:

```
var cnt = $('input[name="items"]').filter((i, el) => el.value.trim() === '').length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if there was a way to select an empty text field without just writing a loop statement.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you'll need a loop. An implicit loop such as this is the most succinct logic you're going to get.

Comment: I just wondered if there was another way. It's okay to use a loop statement. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another method that doesn't require constructing an intermediate array nor a jQuery collection is with `reduce`:

```js
const count = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  $("input[name=items]"),
  (a, input) => $(input).val() === '' ? a + 1 : a,
  0
);
console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="items">
<input name="items">
<input name="items" value="foobar">
<input name="items">
```

You don't need jQuery for this though, since all you really need is to select the matching elements, which you can do with `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const count = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("input[name=items]"),
  (a, input) => input.value === '' ? a + 1 : a,
  0
);
console.log(count);
```

```html
<input name="items">
<input name="items">
<input name="items" value="foobar">
<input name="items">
```

Comment: I am developing back-end only, so the jquery syntax is somewhat unfamiliar. I appreciate your answer and I'll check it out a bit more.

Comment: See edit, there's absolutely no need for jQuery here if you don't feel comfortable with it

Answer (score 0):

Length can be get by a query selector

```
$('input[name="items"][value=""]').length
```

Comment: This is assuming that the `value` hasn't been changed by the user since the page was loaded. Given this seems to be for form validation, then that's a little redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a CSS selector for that:

```
$('input[name=items][value=""], input[name=items]:not([value=""])').length
```

I have combined two selectors together cause if the element doesn't contain the `value` attribute at all you will get the result 0 and for such cases need `input[name=items]:not([value=""])`